# Meaning of the term "Amen Ve'Amen"?

Tags: words, amen

Upon completing a lecture many rabbis end their blessings with the words "Amen Ve'Amen" (True and True). The source for this quote seems to be [Tehillim 41:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16262/jewish/Chapter-41.htm#v=14).

What is meant by the repetition of the word Amen?

Comment: Don't forget "Baruch Hashem L'olam" and other examples from the siddur

Comment: Amen Lolam Hazeh V'amen L'Olam Haba. Do not have time to source now. Perhaps someone else can put in the answer.

Comment: You want the meaning of the words, our why it's used in this certain context?

Comment: @user6591, the meaning.

Comment: @Gershon you got me singing that Lipa Shmelzer song now.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41842&st=&pgnum=261&hilite=

Comment: כל מי שעונה אמן בעולם הזה, זוכה ועונה אמן לעולם הבא. דברים רבה

Comment: Can anyone make sense of this: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_8837_109.pdf? My Hebrew is rusty.

Comment: @AniYodea, he says Amein means "it should be established." In this case it means just like He fulfilling the exile and the suffering He shall fulfill the redemption and the world to come.

Comment: Repetition for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

The earliest source you'll find is in [Bemidbar 5:22](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00763.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2) where the suspected Sota answers Amen-amen to the Cohen's conditional curses.

> וּבָאוּ הַמַּיִם הַמְאָרְרִים הָאֵלֶּה בְּמֵעַיִךְ לַצְבּוֹת בֶּטֶן וְלַנְפִּל יָרֵךְ וְאָמְרָה הָאִשָּׁה **אָמֵן אָמֵן** ‏

The Mishna in [Sota 2:5](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01304.html#HtmpReportNum0012_L2) explains that she's answering Amen to multiple aspects of the curse:

> **עַל מַה הִיא אוֹמֶרֶת אָמֵן אָמֵן**? **אָמֵן** עַל הָאָלָה, **אָמֵן** עַל הַשְּׁבוּעָה. **אָמֵן** מֵאִישׁ זֶה, **אָמֵן** מֵאִישׁ אַחֵר. **אָמֵן** שֶׁלֹּא שָׂטִיתִי אֲרוּסָה  וּנְשׂוּאָה וְשׁוֹמֶרֶת יָבָם וּכְנוּסָה, **אָמֵן** שֶׁלֹּא נִטְמֵאתִי. וְאִם נִטְמֵאתִי, יָבֹאוּ בִי. רַבִּי מֵאִיר אוֹמֵר, **אָמֵן** שֶׁלֹּא נִטְמֵאתִי, **אָמֵן** שֶׁלֹּא אֶטָּמֵא:‏

**So, to answer your question: Amen-VeAmen essentially means "Amen to all we said up to this point".** (*Amen* means "we agree" or "so be it".)

Comment: But this is _Amen Amen_, not _Amen Ve'amen_.

Answer (score 1):

Many interpretations of this verse can be found in [Miqra'ot Gedolot (Tehillim)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=155). I would also recommend the commentary of HaMaLBI"M, though I am currently unable to find it.

One interpretation (Metzudat Dawid), which sticks to the verse's plain meaning is (my translation):

> **אמן**: הוא ענין לשון קיום והכפל לחזק.‏
>
> **Amen**: This is speaking in the language of affirmation, and the double language comes to strength the point.

Another, unique approach is taken by [HaRav 'Ovadiah ben Ya'aqov Seforno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_ben_Jacob_Sforno) in his [commentary on Tehillim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42435&st=&pgnum=43) (my translation):

> יהיה דבר זה נאמן וקיים בשני העולמות
>
> This thing should be dependable and affirmative in both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

"Amen" is more commonly used in a blessing, or when you wish someone well.

When you use "Amen" in a blessing, it actually means "I wish", or "hopefully"... not "yes".

By doubling the "Amen" (Amen ve Amen) - you emphasize your hope for that blessing to come true.

For example in the context of Tehillim:

> "בָּרוּךְ יְהוָה, אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל־מֵהָעוֹלָם, וְעַד הָעוֹלָם: אָמֵן וְאָמֵן." (תהילים מ"א, י"ד)

"Amen ve Amen" is used to end the blessing of "god will be with Israel for all eternity".

By the way - I say Amen ve Amen so often that I ended up calling my website [AmenVAmen](http://amenvamen.com) :)

Comment: "I wish" Hashem creates fruits?

Answer (score 0):

[Siddur Yesod Malchus](http://cdn1.bigcommerce.com/server1200/0e3f5/products/24310/images/15402/li_12518sp__39141.1280440661.1280.1280.jpg?c=2) translates "Amein ve'amein" as "emes hu hadavar."